# Filter & Delete Entire Row

Tags: vba, filter, rows

I am trying to build a code that could filter and delete some 35,000 rows.

I used the below codes but it is taking lot of time(more than 10 mins), can anyone please help me to make it quicker?

Code 1 :

```
Range("$A$1:$S$50000").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="Delete"
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete (xlShiftUp)
```

Code 2 :

```
Dim RngToDelete As Range
Range("$A$1:$S$50000").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="Delete"
Set RngToDelete = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
RngToDelete.Delete
```

Thanks,
Amith

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Performance - 1 million rows - Delete rows containing a value, in less than 1 min](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959315/excel-vba-performance-1-million-rows-delete-rows-containing-a-value-in-less)

Comment: did you already `application.screenupdating = FALSE`? That will save a ton of time.

Comment: Yes i had used - application.screenupdating = FALSE

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the task by using the AdvancedFilter with much faster performance.

**A. Solution without VBA**

Data->Advanced Filter, select 'Filter the list in-place' and fill in the data range and criteria.

**B. Solution With VBA Code**

Range("A1:S50000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Range("U1:U2"), Unique:=False

Do define the criteria with the fieldname (Column 19) on Cell U1 and '<>Delete' on cell U2.  Sure, you can always place your criteria range elsewhere.