# Optimizing loop performance in VBA

Tags: excel, optimization, vba

This is more out of academic interest than any need for a practical solution - I recently wrote a bit of code that does a bunch of filters/sorts/removal of duplicates in a huge file, but as I was stepping through the code it seems like this loop is the main bottleneck and I want to understand why this is so bad, and why the in built functions like filter and sort seem to work so much more quickly doing more difficult operation.

```
For i = 2 To nRows
    If (Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Or Cells(i, 2) <> Cells(i - 1, 2)) _
       And (Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i + 1, 1) Or Cells(i, 2) <> Cells(i + 1, 2)) Then
       Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
       i = i - 1
       nRows = nRows - 1
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Sheet calls in VBA are very slow (compared to arrays or such). Your IF statement alone makes 8 sheet calls every time you loop. A much faster solution would be to read all the data into an array - Do all processing filtering etc on the array then output the array back into the sheet.

Comment: @99moorem thanks, I tried this and got a significant speed up. If you were to write the comment as an answer I'll accept (otherwise I'll do the same as a community wiki answer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959315/excel-vba-performance-1-million-rows-delete-rows-containing-a-value-in-less

Comment: One thing, aside from the speed issue - you're deleting rows but working down through the rows which is why you're having to adjust `i` and `nRows` each time you delete a row.  The accepted way of deleting rows is to work backwards - `For i = nRows To 2 Step -1` - if a row is deleted it doesn't affect the row numbering of any rows above it.

Comment: very good point +1 @DarrenBartrup-Cook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sheet calls in VBA are very slow (compared to arrays or such). 
Your IF statement alone makes 8 sheet calls every time you loop. 
This line: Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete - Makes 4 sheet calls every time you loop.

A much faster solution would be to read all the data into an array - Do all processing filtering etc on the array then output the array back into the sheet.

There is a detailed answer on this with speed comparisons on SO - but I can not find it. If anyone can please add as comment

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you loop through each line, and check logic on each line, there is a lot of overhead.  You could perform an operation hundreds, thousands, or even hundreds of thousands of times.  When you apply a filter, delete what you don't want, unfilter, and sort, you are really only performing four steps in this kind of process.