# Excel VBA - Erase Rows with Union?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this macro by counting backwards to delete rows in a sheet based on a condition. I was wondering if it would be much faster to use `Union` instead somehow and delete only once?

```
Sub bs_erase()
Dim i As Long

With x_bs
    For i = 260 To 1 Step -1
        If Range("C" & i).Value2 = "-" Then
        Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a little broad. Have you tried to write a subroutine that utilizes `Union` to see if it's faster?

Comment: in short, deleting multi-rows at once is much faster than deleting one row at a time.

Comment: Have a look at my previous answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/56473939/11509084]

Comment: gareth thanks thats what I wanted :)