# What is a good way to delete a row if a certain cell is blank in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data with headings. I wish to delete all rows where a cell in column A is blank.

What is an efficient way of doing this for a huge amount of rows.

I currently have

```
Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

But this runs very slow on 10000+ rows

Is there a better or faster way of doing this?

Sorry if this is an age old question
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You show few details. On my admittedly high performance computer, I created a matrix of 20,000 rows and 100 columns. Then cleared a random selection of about 300 different cells in Column A. Your code line deleted the rows in about `0.1 seconds`.  Try turning off `ScreenUpdating` and `Calculation` while you are doing the clearing.

Comment: Some approaches here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959315/excel-vba-performance-1-million-rows-delete-rows-containing-a-value-in-less/33192437#33192437